# Modules not installing globally using for-loop in Python (Google Colab)

Tags: python, for-loop, pip, python-import, google-colaboratory

I'm working in **Google Colabs** and am trying to install packages via a for loop; this is to make the code more readable, allowing me to add more packages easily while following DRY.

The packages do not seem to be installing throughout the runtime though - I get no errors in the loop itself, but I get **"NameError: name 'auth' is not defined"** after.

This indicates to me the packages are only being installed local to the function, but I haven't found a way to fix this or anybody who's used a similar method to install packages. I'd rather not use requirements as I'd like to keep everything in my Colabs Notebook as much as possible.

**Does anyone know how I can get the packages to install globally in the notebook?**

```
#Clear variables - start with a clean slate
for name in dir():
    if not name.startswith('_'):
        del globals()[name]

#Install packages
!pip -q install pip -U
!pip -q check
modules = ["virtualenv",\
           "pandas as pd",\
           "requests",\
           "from google.colab import auth"\
           "io",\
           "from googleapiclient.discovery import build"
           ]

for module in modules:
  if module[:5].lower()=="from":
    exec(module + " -U")
  else:
    !pip install module -U
    import module

#Authenticate the user for Google services
auth.authenticate_user()
print('Authenticated')
# Error1: NameError: name 'auth' is not defined

orders = pd.read_table("link to my data - removed")
# Error2: NameError: name 'pd' is not defined
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who need to know, I think I've now solved the problem by storing my result in a variable in the loop.

I also corrected a few syntax errors such as the string manipulation, but I think setting the variable was the key to resolving the issue. Final result works as below.

```
#Clear variables - start with a clean slate
for name in dir():
    if not name.startswith('_'):
        del globals()[name]

#Install packages
!pip -q install pip -U
!pip -q check
modules = ["virtualenv",\
           "pandas as pd",\
           "requests",\
           "from google.colab import auth",\
           "io",\
           "from googleapiclient.discovery import build"
           ]

for module in modules:
  if module[:4].lower().strip()=="from":
    execution = exec(module)
  else:
    !pip install module -U
    execution = exec("import " + module)

#Authenticate the user for Google services
auth.authenticate_user()
print('Authenticated')
task_service = build('tasks', 'v1')
#Terminal results show user as authenticated

orders = pd.read_table("link to my data - removed")
orders
#Terminal prints the orders table as expected - therefore pd is now recognised as Pandas
```